# Is the inequality of the random matrices correct?

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

I am not familiar with random matrices but I need to confirm the correctness of the inequality below.

> Let $\xi_i\in\{\pm 1\}$ be independent  random signs, and let
> $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ be $m\times m$ Hermitian matrices. Let $\sigma^2 = \|\sum_{i=1}^n Var[\xi_i]A_i^2\|$. Then
> $$Pr\bigg(\bigg\|\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[\xi_i]A_i-\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_iA_i\bigg\|\geq
>  t\bigg)\leq2m\exp(-t^2/2\sigma^2).$$

It is said to be cited from the paper "[User-Friendly Tail Bounds for Sums of Random
Matrices](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emontanar/TEACHING/Stat319/PAPERS/tropp2012user.pdf)
". But I cannot find which results in that paper can imply the inequality. Is the inequality correct?

Note that $\xi_i$ take values in $\{-1,+1\}$ not necessarily equally.

Answer (score 4):

This is equation (4.12) in the cited paper (also at [arXiv:1004.4389](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4389)), which follows from theorem (4.1). The $\xi_i$'s may be independent equally probable random signs, or they may be independent standard normal variables.

Comment: The equation (4.12) is about  Rademacher random variables, which are uniformly distributed on $\{\pm 1\}$, while the inequality I post is about general random signs. You mean (4.12) can imply general case?

Comment: no, the theorem as stated is indeed for the equally probable case; I don't think the inequality holds in the general case, for example, if all $\xi_i$'s equal 1, then $\sigma=0$, the l.h.s. of the equation equals 1, but the r.h.s. can become smaller than 1 for large enough $t$.

Comment: What about $$Pr\bigg(\bigg\|\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[\xi_i]A_i-\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_iA_i\bigg\|\geq
 t\bigg)\leq2m\exp(-t^2/2\sigma^2)?$$

Comment: yep, that would work for $\sigma=0$.

Comment: But we still are not sure whether it  holds for general probability, is that right?