# Is this inequality of the random matrices correct?

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

I need to confirm whether the following inequality correct.

> Let $\xi_i\in\{\pm 1\}$ be independent  random signs, and let
> $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ be $m\times m$ Hermitian matrices. Let $\sigma^2 = \|\sum_{i=1}^n Var[\xi_i]A_i^2\|$. Then
> $$Pr\bigg(\bigg\|\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[\xi_i]A_i-\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_iA_i\bigg\|\geq
>  t\bigg)\leq2m\exp(-t^2/2\sigma^2).$$

It is said to be cited from the paper "[User-Friendly Tail Bounds for Sums of Random
Matrices](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emontanar/TEACHING/Stat319/PAPERS/tropp2012user.pdf)
". I can only find   Theorem 1.5, which is only for normal distribution or equal probability for ${-1,+1}$ .
Is the inequality correct?

Note that the inequality is slightly different from a previous [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366017/is-the-inequality-of-the-random-matrices-correct/366021#366021).  The inequality in that post is false accroding to a comment.